# How do I erase last character of a string without "erase()"?

Tags: c++, string, char, erase

I am trying to erase the last character of a string without "erase()",

> from "ABC" to "AB"

I tried setting the last character to NULL `a[strlen(a) - 1] = NULL`, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: [`std::string::pop_back`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/pop_back/?kw=string%3A%3Apop_back)

Comment: `a.resize(2)` ? Its not quite clear what the problem is. Can you show your code?

Comment: why can't you use erase?

Comment: `a.resize(a.length()-1);` if length > 0.

Comment: Do you mean a std::string ? your own attempt suggests you may be using a C style (null terminated array of characters)...

Comment: `NULL` is a null **pointer**. Don't use it as any sort of numeric type. It **might** be defined as 0, but that is not required, and in some implementations is is not 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++11, then:

```
a.pop_back();
```

Alternatively:

```
if (a.size () > 0)  
a.resize(a.size()-1);
```

Comment: The `a.size()>0` check always makes sense, also for `pop_back`. Of course the question presupposes that there **is** a last character.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `substr()` if you want to preserve original string.

```
std::string b = a.substr (0,a.length()-1);
```